# Kivy TextInput how can start typing from the right

Tags: python, kivy

I am building a simple calculator with kivy how can I make the cursor automatically start typing from right to left

Comment: Post your code of what you have tried

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's not that simple. Not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for, but here is an extension of `TextInput` that I wrote for a similar case. It keeps the text right adjusted. Note that this is expecting the text to be a legitimate floating point number. If you don't want that restriction, just remove the code where `float` is called:

```
class FloatInputRight(TextInput):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(FloatInputRight, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.multiline = False

    def right_adjust(self, text):
        if text == '':
            return text
        max_width = self.width - self.padding[0] - self.padding[2]
        new_text = text
        text_width = self._get_text_width(new_text, self.tab_width, self._label_cached)
        while text_width < max_width:
            new_text = ' ' + new_text
            text_width = self._get_text_width(new_text, self.tab_width, self._label_cached)
        while text_width >= max_width:
            if new_text[0] != ' ':
                break
            else:
                new_text = new_text[1:]
                text_width = self._get_text_width(new_text, self.tab_width, self._label_cached)
        return new_text

    def on_size(self, instance, value):
        super(FloatInputRight, self).on_size(instance, value)
        if len(self._lines) == 0:
            return True
        cc, cr = self.cursor
        cur_text = self._lines[cr]
        initial_len = len(cur_text)
        super(FloatInputRight, self)._refresh_text(self.right_adjust(cur_text))
        final_len = len(self._lines[cr])
        self.cursor = self.get_cursor_from_index(final_len - (initial_len - cc))
        return True

    def delete_selection(self, from_undo=False):
        if not self._selection:
            return
        cr = self.cursor[1]
        initial_len = len(self._lines[cr])
        a, b = self._selection_from, self._selection_to
        if a > b:
            a, b = b, a
        super(FloatInputRight, self).delete_selection(from_undo=from_undo)
        cur_text = self._lines[cr]
        super(FloatInputRight, self)._refresh_text(self.right_adjust(cur_text))
        final_len = len(self._lines[cr])
        self.cursor = self.get_cursor_from_index(final_len - (initial_len - b))

    def do_backspace(self, from_undo=False, mode='bkspc'):
        cc, cr = self.cursor
        initial_len = len(self._lines[cr])
        super(FloatInputRight, self).do_backspace(from_undo=from_undo, mode=mode)
        cc, cr = self.cursor
        cur_text = self._lines[cr]
        super(FloatInputRight, self)._refresh_text(self.right_adjust(cur_text))
        final_len = len(self._lines[cr])
        self.cursor = self.get_cursor_from_index(final_len - (initial_len-cc) + 1)

    def insert_text(self, the_text, from_undo=False):
        cc, cr = self.cursor
        cur_text = self._lines[cr]
        initial_len = len(cur_text)
        new_text = self.right_adjust(cur_text[:cc] + the_text + cur_text[cc:])
        try:
            num = float(new_text) # throw exception if new_text is invalid float
        except ValueError:
            return
        self._lines[cr] = ''
        super(FloatInputRight, self).insert_text(new_text, from_undo=from_undo)
        final_len = len(self._lines[cr])
        self.cursor = self.get_cursor_from_index(final_len - (initial_len-cc))

    def set_right_adj_text(self, text):
        num = float(text)  # throws exception if text is invalid float
        self._refresh_text(self.right_adjust(text))
```